# C# - Using a NotifyIcon from an User Control

Tags: c#, winforms

This is something that surprisingly wasn't able to find a solution online.

I have in my main form a couple of user control, that after doing a certain action, I want to show a notification icon.

The examples shown about doing from a different form don´t apply to User Controls, as you can't directly reference the form that is using it.

In the case the question is a bit confusing:

```
Application
- Main Form
--NotifyIcon
--UserControl
---Button that when pressed, show the NotifyIcon
--UserControl
---Button that when pressed, show the NotifyIcon
```

I´m using VS2010 by the way.

Comment: *"as you can't directly reference the form"* >> You can get a reference to the parent form pretty easily: If the UserControl is directly placed on the form you can just get the reference from the [`Control.Parent` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.parent(v=vs.110).aspx), otherwise you could just use the [`Control.FindForm()` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.findform(v=vs.110).aspx) to find the parent form containing the UserControl.

Comment: Decoupling the control from its parent is a standard programming technique.  Have the UserControl raise an event.  Passing the NotifyIcon reference through a public property is possible as well but not nearly as pretty.  Do keep in mind that NotifyIcon is useful when the UI is hidden, that is a decision made by the form and not a control.